# Invalid key hash when trying to log into Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, apk, keystore

I recently made my Android application that I made available to alpha testers on the `Google Play Store` and I want them to be able to login to my application via Facebook login. The issue is, every time they log in, their application crashes due to an error that says:

`Invalid key hash.The key hash <Key Hash> does not match any stored key hashes.`

I understand I need to add this into my application's development / key hashes in the `Settings` tab in my application on the `Facebook Developer Console`

As a result, I tried to do the following:

When I first boot up the application, I have the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());        
        Log.d("Result: ", String.valueOf(FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(getApplicationContext())));
        ...
}
```

And once my application runs, I grab this value that is printed in the `Result:` call and I made sure that the hash generated is the same hash that I have in my `Facebook Developer Console Development/Release hash key` section. I also made sure that when I published my application's APK, I grabbed the correct release key hash because I also made my application production-ready on the `Facebook Developer Console`. Here is me generating my `signed APK` so that I can publish this to the `Google Play Developer Console`:

[image: Generating Signed APK for Google Play publishing]

And here is me trying to generate the release AND debug hash key for my application:

[image: Getting the Key Store hashes for Facebook]

I made sure to make my application public on the `Facebook Developer Console` and also my application is published on the `Google Developer Play Console`. I seem to be able to download the application from the link given to alpha testers but they do not seem to be able to download it. Is there anything I've done wrong in trying to set up the development/release hash of my Facebook keystore so that my alpha testers can login properly? Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this could be openssl issue. Recently for debug purpose i generated a key which was different than the key generated through code.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar so what do you suggest I try if it is an openssl issue?

Comment: Try download openssl from different site. Or if you could build yourself from source https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL